# Changing the location of an existing VBA Reference from C:\Windows\system32\ to a shared drive

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vb6

I've been trying for a while now to get a reference file to be loaded externally to no avail.

To be specific I am trying to load a "Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0(SP4)" which usually resides in C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCT2.OCX

However some people that run a macro containing this element don't have that "MSCOMCT2.OCX" file on their PCs so I thought I will move the MSCOMCT2.OCX to a shared location and reference the code to use the shared one instead (so everyone will have access to it)

I tried doing that but when I was trying to load a reference with "Browse" from a different location it didn't load it - because I already had that in C:..

So I thought OK... I will remove the file from C:\ so I can only reference the shared file. - so I deleted it.
So I open the workbook again and look at references - I cant find "Microsotft Windows Common Controls-2.6.0(SP4)" - great!
And I proceed to add it manually with Browse from the shared drive.
When I do that however 2 references of "Microsotft Windows Common Controls-2.6.0(SP4)" are being added - 1 from C:\(which is not there) and 1 from the shared drive.

[image: Reference automatically added from C:\]

[image: Reference also added from Shared drive]

The one from C:\ is always automatically selected.
If I try to disable the one from C:\ and enable the one from the shared drive it automatically changes back to what it was when i press OK.
If I try to enable both - it says duplicate References and keeps only the one from C:\

So.. does anybody know how can I get rid of that C:\ reference from the list so it doesn't get loaded? Apparently deleting the files themselves did not work.
Ultimately my goal is to enable people without C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCT2.OCX file to be able to use my Date Picker Tool.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: They don't have the control because it is a licensed VB6 control library.  You cannot legally share it for other people to use at design time - and generic Office editions only support design time operation.  Office (and Excel) do not have a license to use this library except in the case of Developer Editions of Office (or the VSTO/VSTA add-on products).

Comment: thanks for the additional info

Comment: Well in case it isn't clear, what you are attempting is piracy.  To make it legal you'd need to license one of the Office Developer packages.  Which one you need depends on your Office version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActiveX control rereferences are *always* GUID-based. The VB IDE shows you the current location of the file as listed in the registry on your computer, as a courtesy, but it really doesn't matter what it says. The control will be loaded from wherever it was registered on the user's computer.

That's the key: the control must be registered on the user's computer.

I must strongly discourage you from doing what you're trying to do. You might be able to concoct a method by which you load the DLL from a network location, but it presents no advantage over doing the Right Thing(TM), and plenty of problems. The Right Thing is simply that if you need that control, you must distribute and register it with your application, just like everybody else does. And you really should install it in the recommended location for it (System32); not on the network.

Here's a quick example of what can go wrong: you provide your user with you app, and it works with the control on the network like you want it. Then the user installs another application that happens to need the same control. The app's installer sees that the control is already registered on the user's computer, so it doesn't try to add it again. Except that this particular app is intended to be used when the user is not connected to a network. Now you just broke someone else's program.

The VB/VBA architecture was never intended to support XCOPY deployment. I'm know it's a pain and that these extra steps are extremely inconvenient when you're just trying to deploy a "macro". Sadly, it's the nature of the beast. I'm sorry

Comment: Well, my example was a bit far-fetched because installers normally look for the file, not the COM registration. Other examples: a serious security patch is issued by Microsoft for the control; Windows Update won't be able to apply the patch. Or: program B installs an older version of the OCX (because it doesn't see the one on the network) and now your app fails in mysterious ways. Or: there is a network glitch, and that causes Excel to crash. Or: you have to update the OCX but you can't because someone somewhere is always using your macro. I could go all day...

Comment: +1. Was about to say exactly the same thing, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw: i'm curious: you mean the post? Or the comment I added later?

Comment: thanks for the answer. guess its not gonna work like that... regarding updating the code..I use a shared (read-only) workbook where all the macros are located, and I have given a ribbon customisation file to everyone who just imports the customisation file (with ribbon buttons that call a macro from the shared workbook and then close itself). That way to update everyone's code I only need to update that specific workbook(after making it not read-only) so that way i dont have the "workbook is in use" issue.

Comment: @PotterRafed, the problem would not be the workbook; it would be the workbook causing Excel to load and lock the OCX. And typically Excel (VBA really) would hold onto the OCX until the process terminates.

Comment: Actually VB6 programs do support XCopy deployment with some restrictions.  The problem is that when Microsoft created the infrastructure for WinXP they never provided VB6 tooling for it so you have to use a 3rd party product to generate the manifests or try to stretch VS.Net tools to do the job.  But Office macros are another topic altogether.

Comment: @Bob77, in some ways it's backwards. WinXP (RTM, IIRC) was the first OS to ship with the VB6 runtime, and that made it possible for the first time to create a program that could be XCOPY-deployed, so long as you didn't use any COM objects that weren't also per-shipped. Before that, you always had to ship and install at least the VB6 runtime, one way or another. Due to that, I stick to the statement that, in the Win98 era when VB6 was released, VB was not designed to create XCOPY-deployable programs.

Comment: Yet registration-free COM introduced in Windows XP was specifically designed for VB6.  VB6 has not been static, to use it you need a late version of the runtime components such as SP6.  You can use this to create VB6 programs that use ActiveX OCXs and DLLs without registering them.  That plus the preinstalled runtime and you have XCopy deployable VB6 programs.