# How to generate email drafts without Outlook

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am building an Access form that will be deployed on Windows machines without Office.  To run the Access db, the [Office 2010 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) routine will be installed.  Thanks to this handy free download, the user can open forms and run custom code without having Access installed.

This is perfect with one exception.  After entering their data, I need some custom code that will open and save a Draft email in an MS Exchange account.  Normally, this would be very easy for me using Outlook. However, the Office Runtime I mentioned earlier doesn't include the library.

How do I *legally* use the MS Outlook 14.0 Object Library (MSOUTL.OLB) on machines that don't have Outlook installed? Ideas so far:

1. Does the desktop version of Outlook Express install this library? I can only find this on 3rd party [sites](http://outlook-express.soft32.com/), so it's not my first choice.
2. I explored the idea of just copying the libraries over to a shared drive, but that doesn't seem like a good [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832711/changing-the-location-of-an-existing-vba-reference-from-c-windows-system32-to).
3. That's all I have. If it's simply not possible, I'll need to make a new interface and management system for someone else to generate the emails instead.

Suggestions please?

(Also, for those of you who like to see code, here's what I'd normally do. Except I would modify this to log into a specific account:)

```
Function MakeEmail()
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim ObjMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ObjMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'Add To,CC,Subject,Body,etc here
    ObjMail.Save
End Function
```

Comment: If memory serves, Outlook and Outlook Express are unrelated, codewise.

Comment: You need some Email client app if you want to send any emails from client machines. Be it Windows Mail, Outlook Express, Windows Live Mail, Eudora, Thunderbird etc. Or write a crafted text file to network share and have an Outlook macro on one machine to monitor this share. Alternatively launch a portable email client app from network share.

Comment: Fair enough.  What email client do you recommend? I'm trying to access the MS Exchange account via VBA and I only want to save the email as a draft, not actually send it (the actual sending will be done by a second human being who will review it for accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

Download the [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) command line utility. Then modify your VBA to execute that instead.

```
Sub SendEmail(fromAddress As String, _
                   toAddress As String, _
                   subject As String, _
                   message As String, _
                   server As String, _
                   userID As String, _
                   userPass As String _
                   )
    Shell "sendemail.exe -f " & fromAddress & _
        " -t " & toAddress & _
        " -u " & subject & _
        " -m " & message & _
        " -s " & server & _
        " -xu " & userID & _
        " -xp " & userPass & _
        , vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but instead of sending it, can I use this util to save the email as a draft on a MS Exchange server? A human will need to review it first. I'm looking at the link and I don't think I see that option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the version of Exchange Server that is in use, you could try making use of CDO.  I believe it should have the ability to create an Exchange session, create a message object, and then place that in a specific folder (i.e. Drafts).

For more information, check out the MSDN article on CDO [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527795%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx), and look for any download you might need [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171440).